# Manager isn't accessible via WatchList instances How do I fix this error?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create an e-commerce site (CS50 Project 2) through Django and have a Django view with multiple forms. In this view I am trying to use a Boolean Field in a Django form to enable the user to add a listing to his watchlist, both of which are models. While trying to do that, I am receiving the above error.

part of the views.py

```
def listing(request, id):
    #gets listing
    listing = Listings.objects.get(id=id)
    watchlist_form = WatchListForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        watchlist_form = WatchListForm(request.POST)
        if watchlist_form.is_valid():
            watchlist = watchlist_form.save(commit=False)
            watchlist.user = request.user
            watchlist.add_to_watchlist = True
            new_watchlist_listing = watchlist.objects.listings.add(listing) 
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
                "auction_listing": listing,
                "watchlistForm": watchlist_form
            })
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
                "auction_listing": listing,
                "form": comment_form,
                "comments": comment_obj,
                "bidForm": bid_form,
                "bids": bid_obj,
                "watchlistForm": watchlist_form
            })
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
        "auction_listing": listing,
        "form": comment_form,
        "comments": comment_obj,
        "bidForm": bid_form,
        "bids": bid_obj,
        "watchlistForm": watchlist_form
    })
```

models.py

```
class Listings(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = [
    ("Miscellaneous", "Miscellaneous"),
    ("Movies and Television", "Movies and Television"),
    ("Sports", "Sports"),
    ("Arts and Crafts", "Arts and Crafts"),
    ("Clothing", "Clothing"),
    ("Books", "Books"),
]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000000000000, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=CATEGORY, default=None)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")


class WatchList(models.Model):
    listings = models.ManyToManyField(Listings)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    add_to_watchlist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

error message

```
raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % cls.__name__)
AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via WatchList instances
```

This error is happening because of this line: `new_watchlist_listing = watchlist.objects.listings.add(listing)`.

Comment: `watchlist.listings.add(listing)`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, doing that creates this error: ```"<WatchList: WatchList object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.```

Comment: as the error says, you first need to `watchlist.save()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add elements with `modelobject.manytomanyfield.add()`, so without the <s>`.objects`</s> part. Your view should thus look like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

@login_required
def listing(request, id):
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listings.objects, pk=id)
    watchlist_form = WatchListForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        watchlist_form = WatchListForm(request.POST)
        if watchlist_form.is_valid():
            watchlist_form.instance.user = request.user
            watchlist_form.instance.add_to_watchlist = True
            watchlist = watchlist_form.save()
            watchlist.listings.add(listing)
            return redirect('name-of-the-view')
    return render(request, 'auctions/listing.html',{
        'auction_listing': listing,
        'form': comment_form,
        'comments': comment_obj,
        'bidForm': bid_form,
        'bids': bid_obj,
        'watchlistForm': watchlist_form
    })
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: Usually it is better not to work with `commit=False` when saving the form with the [**`.save(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method): this will revent saving many-to-many relations since these can only be saved if the item is committed. Usually it is better to alter the `.instance` wrapped in the form. For more information, see [my article<sup>[Django-antippaterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/using-commit-false-when-altering-the-instance-in-a-modelform.html) on this.